# Data Masking in Amazon RDS(PostgreSql, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, data-masking

We were checking the documentation for data-masking on Amazon RDS instances, but we couldn't find much information on it. I have seen some blogs from Amazon tagged as data masking, but those are referring to security best practices for RDS. Would you guide me to do data-masking on RDS. Please share if you have any reference documents. Does Amazon released any blogs related to this topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify which type of data masking you want to implement (Static or Dynamic). I guess that you want to implement dynamic masking for specific users.

Data Masking implemented in different ways in each RDS databases and you can't find a universal solution in Amazon. Some RDS databases (like MsSQL and Oracle) have builtin masking capabilities and others (like MySQL and Postgres) don't have builtin masking. You can learn about 3rd party solutions like [DataSunrise](https://www.datasunrise.com/dynamic-data-masking/). It is revers-proxy which can mask data on the fly.